# Suggested edit for "automatically inserted text" duplicate question block?

Tags: discussion, review, edits, suggested-edits, duplicate-questions

Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5570834) suggested edit - where it looks like a low-rep user is suggesting an edit to manually insert the "automatically inserted text" identifying a question as a potential duplicate - **normal/legit?**

I thought this sort of thing was automatically added by the Community user (based on my cursory lookup of similar questions on meta). Why would something like this go through the Suggested Edit queue?  If this is legit, as Suggested Edit reviewers, how can we tell the difference?

Comment: And no surprise there was a robo approver there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was a comment (now deleted) that pointed out that his question is possibly a duplicate:

> possible duplicate of another duplicate [Pass by pointer & Pass by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571078)

This comment was deleted by its author. I'm guessing that the user who proposed the edit went to that question and straight up copied the "possible duplicate" block to use in their suggested edit.

I have no doubt that this user had the best intentions, but this is certainly not the right way to go about this and the edit was correctly rejected. Flagging or voting to close as a duplicate is the way to go.

Since the Great Flag Refactoring of 2013, closing as a duplicate no longer inserts an editable block into the post, but questions that were closed before that time still have it. There is no situation in which this would be a legitimate suggested edit, and if you ever see it again, you should not hesitate to hit "reject". (And then check the links and see if you should flag/vote to close as well.)

Comment: There is one situation where this would be a legitimate suggested edit: if it's to roll back a previous edit that removed the header block from a closed question. It's extremely rare but I've seen it.

Comment: @Gilles Ah, yeah, I can see that. In those cases, I hope the editor leaves a reasonable edit summary to help tell this case apart from the rest.